# What are the actual mechanics by which the BPF Upgradeable Loader's upgrade method updates a the entry point of a Solana program?

Tags: solana-program, upgrade

H:

I am trying to understand the mechanics of the BPF Upgradeable Loader's `upgrade` method. The thing that is confusing me is that by definition all data stored on a blockchain is immutable, yet something about the program (and it parts) is mutable.

I understand that the `upgrade` method will create a new instance of the program. But, I am unclear at a nuts and bolts level how a new, updated program is linked to the original program account without violating immutability.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I really want to understand how all this works.

Answer (score 1):

Solana programs are mutable by default, because they have an upgrade authority. They can become immutable by removing that authority, or kinda-immutable if you simply burn the private key after deployment.

Everything on-chain is just data at an address. If you have the key, you can change the data at that address. Upgrading a program is just that. Then the loader reads the data, validates it is executable, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an audit trail by which I can monitor changes?

Also, it is accurate to think that it is still NOT possible to change data in a block? Wouldn't that corrupt the nonces in the chain?